# Formatting checkboxes with Bootstrap in Rails form erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I'm using multiple check boxes in my Rails views form. I'm using Bootstrap 4 for styling. If there is a Bootstrap style for checkboxes like:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <div class="input-group-text">
      <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with checkbox">
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <div class="input-group-text">
      <input type="radio" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button">
</div>
```

how do I implement multiple class stylings into an erb object? Here is the code I'm trying to implement:

```
            <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:authorization_ids, Authorization.all, :id, :auth_name, { checked: @account.try { |a| a.authorization_ids.map(&:to_param) } }, multiple: true, # WOULD LIKE TO IMPLEMENT BOOTSTRAP CLASSES HERE ) %>
        <%= f.label :authorization_ids, 'Authorizations' %>
```

**UPDATE**

Some great responses here. I ended up using `bootstrap_form_with` from the 
`rails_bootstrap_form` Gem. I used a custom wrapper class for styling and was able to get the checkboxes in nice orderly columns and rows.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class='form-group'>
                <%= bootstrap_form_with(model: @account) do |f| %>
                <%= f.text_field :account_name %>
                <%= f.text_field :account_address_line1 %>
                <%= f.text_field :account_address_line2 %>
                <%= f.text_field :account_city %>
                <%= f.select :account_state, states %>
                <%= f.text_field :account_zipcode %>
                <%= f.text_field :contact_first_name %>
                <%= f.text_field :contact_last_name %>
                <%= f.email_field :contact_email %>
                <%= f.telephone_field :contact_phone %>
                <%= f.select :account_ppu, ppu, placeholder: "Select PPU...." %>
                <%= f.text_area :account_notes %>
            </div>

            <%= f.collection_check_boxes :authorization_ids, Authorization.all, :id, :auth_name, hide_label: true, wrapper: {class: "cp-container-class"} %>
        </div>
        <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Styling:

```
@import "bootstrap";
 @import "rails_bootstrap_forms";
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Thambi+2|Lato&display=swap');

 body {
     margin: 0px;
 }


#logo {
     margin: 1em;
     padding: 1em;
     width: 500px;
     height: auto;

 }

 .cp-container-class {
     width: 1000px;
     height: 500px;
     justify-items: center; 
    flex-direction:column;
      padding: 10px;
     /* Change to whatever*/
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     border: black 1px solid;
 }

 .cp-container-class>* {
     flex: 1 1 20px; 
     margin-left: 50px; 
     letter-spacing: 5px;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes) for `collection_check_boxes`, you can add HTML classes by using a builder, like this:

```
collection_check_boxes(:post, :author_ids, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial) do |b|
  b.label(class: "check_box") { b.check_box(class: "check_box") }
end
```

In terms of your situation, it would look something like this:

```
collection_check_boxes(:authorization_ids, Authorization.all, :id, :auth_name, { checked: @account.try { |a| a.authorization_ids.map(&:to_param) } }, multiple: true) do |b|
  b.label(class: "some-class another-class") { b.check_box(class: "a-class a-different-class") }
end
```

That might not be exactly what you want; you might have to play around with it a bit.

Comment: Yeah this would make sense but doesn't seem to take with `collection` in Rails.

Comment: @DemianSims I updated my answer. Hopefully that's what you're looking for!

Comment: This is so close now. It seems to be an either/or with `b.label` and `b.check_box` but not both.

Comment: @DemianSims Do you mind editing your question to reflect the code you have now? You should be able to apply both `label` classes and `check_box` classes. I would use your browser's inspect tools to see what the HTML looks like when you try to apply classes to both elements. That could give a clue as to what is happening.

Comment: @DemianSims Glad to hear you've had some success with the checkboxes. In your updated code, you didn't use the builder I suggested in this answer (using `collection_check_boxes` with the `do |b|` block). Did you try using that builder to set classes for the label and checkboxes? What is the result? And what part are you stuck on now?

Comment: I did try to use the building but still had an issue with either/or regarding label or checkbox. Not stuck now but really like the builder method and wondering if you know what the either/or?

Comment: @DemianSims I'd like to help, but "an issue with either/or" is too vague for me to know what is going on. Could you add to your answer both (1) The code you tried (with the builder), and (2) The error you got?